# asp.net MVC 4 redirect to details after creating a new item in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

hopefully someone can help me.

I am creating a website where people can make bookings that are saved to a database.

The problem I have is that when someone creates a booking on the website it takes them back to the index view for that controller, which shows everything in the database.

But, I want it to take them to the details view for their booking once they click the create button.

I hope that's clear.  My Create code is:

```
     // POST: /Booking/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Booking booking)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Bookings.Add(booking);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(booking);
    }
```

if I try replacing

```
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

with

```
     return RedirectToAction("Details");
```

I get an error, but there must be a simple way to do it?  can anyone point out where I'm going wrong please?

Thanks.

Comment: It can't find an action `Details`.  Is it in another controller?  Can you show your `Details` action?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Booking booking)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Bookings.Add(booking);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { bookingId = booking.Id });
    }

    return View(booking);
}

public ActionResult Details(int bookingId)
{
    var details = GetBookingDetails(bookingId); //Load details
    return View(details);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your details action will certainly need the id of the booking you wish to display the details for.  Does your details action look like this?

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
```

Assuming your booking class has an integer Id property you would most likely need

```
return RedirectToAction("Details","<ControllerName>", new{id=booking.Id});
```

Comment: ah, sorry saw the below post first, but yes, that did it. thanks.